# Why isn't my angular code working w/ Sublime2?

Tags: angularjs

I was just testing out angular and am wonder why nothing is showing up when I load up the page. I installed AngularJS through Package install already. Is there something wrong here?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Journal.css">
    <title>Henry's journal</title>
</head>

<body>  
    <div ng-app="journal">
    <div header></div>
    </div>
    <div>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Journal.js"></script>
        <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type ="text/javascript"
           src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js">
        </script>   
</body>

</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    var journal = angular.module("journal", []);
    journal.directive("header", function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(){
                alert("I'm working");
            },
            template: "<div>Hello!</div>"
        };
    });
```

Comment: SublimeText is just an editor, no?

Comment: @Sergio Yeah I'm just wondering why this code isn't rendering. Wondering if it's a problem with sublime or with my code

Comment: Definitely with the code :)

Comment: @Sergio care for hint =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load AngularJS and jQuery *before* running your own script. Like so:

```
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js">  </script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="Journal.js"></script>
```

(Additionally, you might be running into a *different* issue if you are testing locally using the `file://` protocol. I'm not sure, but just in case: you'll have to specify a HTTP[s] protocol to load AngularJS: `http://ajax.googleapis.com...` instead of `//ajax.googleapis.com...`)

Comment: thank you, this fixed it. It was actually a combo of both. Thanks a lot, this was tripping me up for a good hour

Answer (score 1):

you have to add ng-app in the first HTML tag.

`<html ng-app>
<!-- ...head...body -->
</html>`

Perhaps this is an easier version of your app:

```
<html ng-app="journal">
<script type ="text/javascript"
       src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js">
    </script>   

<title>jojo</title>

<div ng-controller="hola">

</div>




<script>
    angular.module("journal", [])
    .controller("hola", function($scope){
        alert('HOLEAAA!');
    })

</script>

</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: That is not necessary. See my answer below.

Comment: Now try.. and then let me know asap.. :)))